# Laravel 5.2 artisan optimize

Tags: laravel-5

Seem to be having an issue when I run artisan optimize on my production server.

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                 
php_strip_whitespace(SITE): failed to open stream: No child processes
```

Anyone come across anything similar?

I have tried clearing cache files, with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered this question on [Laravel 5.2 artisan optimize - php_strip_whitespace failed to open stream: No child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681541/laravel-5-2-artisan-optimize-php-strip-whitespace-failed-to-open-stream-no-ch)

In short, replace your config/compile.php with the 5.2 version in the Laravel repo. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/config/compile.php