# Laravel 5.2 artisan optimize - php_strip_whitespace failed to open stream: No child processes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, circleci

Since upgrading to Laravel 5.2 from 5.1, when running **artisan optimize** on CircleCI, running PHP 5.6.14, I am getting

```
[ErrorException]                                                                                 
php_strip_whitespace(/var/laravel/project/root): failed to open stream: No child processes
```

Where **/var/laravel/project/root** is the directory where composer.json and vendor reside.

The command runs fine on my dev box running PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1. I followed the official 5.1 to 5.2 upgrade guide.

```
Exception trace:
() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/classpreloader/classpreloader/src/ClassPreloader.php:124
Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
php_strip_whitespace() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/classpreloader/classpreloader/src/ClassPreloader.php:124
ClassPreloader\ClassPreloader->getCode() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php:83
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->compileClasses() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/OptimizeCommand.php:64
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\OptimizeCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
call_user_func_array() at /var/laravel/project/root/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1217
Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:787
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/laravel/project/root/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /var/laravel/project/root/artisan:36
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this please?

Comment: The error appears yo be something to do with the class loader/optimizer trying to load a class/file which doesn't exist. Try checking your config/app.php for any classes you may have added. Also try dumping composer auto-loads.

Comment: Where you able to solve it?

Comment: @RCrowt I have tried using the default config/app.php from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/master/config/app.php but no luck. Yes, I've tried composer dump-autoload, again no luck.

Comment: @NestorMataCuthbert Not yet. I'm out of ideas at the moment.

Comment: Yes, me too, I've tried everything, but the creepy error is still there, although, the site seems to work just fine, but I guess the only payout is that the optimisation is not done, It would have to do for now, I'll keep searching for something and let you know if I see a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer on https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-optimize-error where johnwheal mentions that `config/compile.php` is wrong.

It turns out that the files array in `config/compile.php` was emptied in a commit in April 2015 <strike>but I can't see the change mentioned in the *Upgrade Guide*</strike>. It has since been added to the *Upgrade Guide*.

To fix the problem either:

- Empty the files array in `config/compile.php`

**or**

- Remove `BusServiceProvider.php` and `ConfigServiceProvider.php` from the files array in `config/compile.php`
  .

Comment: There is already a PR to add this to the docs. https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/2056

Comment: I confirm that this fixes the problem

Comment: Do not empty the files array. Just remove the line with the two missing providers.

Comment: @mniess if this is the recommended solution why is the default in Laravel 5.2 to have the array empty? See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php

Comment: @DaveSouthey That's a good question. It should clearly improve the performance to have the providers in there.

Comment: @DaveSouthey I am not sure, however if you read the docs it states "If present, remove the following lines from config/compile.php in the files array:". See under "Compiled Classes" on "Upgrading To 5.2.0 From 5.1". Clearly there's disparity between their docs and their source.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is the `BusServiceProvider` and `ConfigServiceProvider` have been removed, as part of the 5.1 to 5.2 transition. Although the answer provided to remove all compiled classes will fix the problem, the only two you need to remove is `BusServiceProvider` and `ConfigServiceProvider` from `config/compile.php`.

`'files' => [
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'),
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php'), // This one
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php'), // And this one
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php'),
        realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php'),
    ],`

Comment: ConfigServiceProvider has also been removed. Also the default in Laravel 5.2 is to have the files array empty. See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php.

Comment: @DaveSouthey agreed (updated answer), although you can still benefit from compilation by keeping the remaining items in there :). Laravel have [updated their upgrade docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade) and now only mention removing the two items above.

Comment: if this is the recommended solution why is the default in Laravel 5.2 to have the array empty? See http://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php